# Jax rs rest client - timeout configuration

Tags: rest, jax-rs, jax-ws, resttemplate, restful-architecture

I am using a jax.ws.rs client for invoking rest Services... Recently I was trying to configure the time out settings for the client but it seems it's not directly supported via jax.ws.rs.

Can someone guide me what is the best possible way to configure such timeouts.

Also can someone please suggest what is the best way to test these timeouts... The services that we are consuming are all 3rd party based.

Regards,
Vicky

Comment: I checked the link and it didn't help me I used the string based properties and specified the value as 1 even then wasn't able to invoke timeout exception, Is there a generic way of specifying the time outs.. I am running the application over jboss app server.

Comment: Which version of Jboss and is it EAP or Wildfly?

Comment: We are using wildfly

Comment: Which version though, 10, 11 or 12?

Comment: Apologies I missed that part... We are using wildfly 9.2

Comment: Have you tried these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543209/how-to-set-the-connection-and-read-timeout-with-jersey-2-x and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42905685/set-timeout-for-jax-rs-client they may just be variations but worth a try.  If those aren't working, the only thing I could think of doing would be to configure the timeouts in undertow - but this would affect everything web related